# Android Hardware Acceleration

Tags: android, hardware-acceleration

I have an custom View.When I open hardware acceleration and use function Canvas.drawPath() to draw a long Path, this path cannot be drawn. But when I close hardware acceleration, this problem will disappear. However, hardware acceleration is necessary to ensure the interface run smoothly.How could I do to solve this problem？

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650273/android-canvas-didnt-draw-path-when-paths-point-out-of-view

Comment: I know this problem can be solved as you suggested.But if I close hardware acceleration, custom view cannot move fluently.I wanna know how to  solve this problem with the hardware acceleration open?

Answer (score 0):

If your path does not change much, you could draw it to a bitmap and then reuse the bitmap in `onDraw`. If you need to animate it @60fps, you could use a `TextureView` and draw your path in openGL..It's more code but it should also be significantly faster.